# Can a XML namespace name be something other than an HTTP URI?

Tags: xml, xaml, xml-namespaces

The way I understand it, an XML namespace name can be any valid URI; however, it seems that they're *always* URIs with the `http://` scheme. Is this a rule, a guideline, just a convention? Can I use something like `urn:foo:bar` instead?

Here's my specific usage scenario: I want to define an XML namespace for a library of mine, to make its usage easier in XAML. I could use the URL of the GitHub repository, but if the project's home ever changes, the namespace name will become an obsolete URL (and if I change it, it will break existing code). So I'm thinking of using an URI like `urn:myname:myproject` instead.

Is this a acceptable practice? If not, what would be a good way to handle the fact that the project's home might change, making the URL obsolete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Can a XML namespace name be something other than an HTTP URI?"*

Sure it can. The official documentation of *['Namespaces in XML'](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/)* mention about criteria of a namespace identifier, and in the same place mention about URN and URL as possible candidates for the task  :

> The namespace name, to serve its intended purpose, should have the **characteristics of uniqueness and persistence**. It is not a goal that it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any exists). An example of a syntax that is designed with these goals in mind is that for **Uniform Resource Names** [[RFC2141]](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#URNs). However, it should be noted that ordinary **URL**s can be managed in such a way as to achieve these same goals.

So, as long as the URI you're going to use carries the recommended characteristics, I would say it is acceptable practice to use it.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation is quite explicit. It even contains examples of URN namespace names.